# Synchronize all current users in bash script using mkfifo pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm creating a program written in bash script that manages users and groups. I want to reload all current users when I add or delete a user in a specific tab. I tried to use mkfifo fpipe but it only reloads all users when I restart the app. Any ideas to solve this problem? Below is the code that performs this function.

```
mkfifo "$fpipe"

trap "rm -f $fpipe $fts" EXIT

fpipe="OUTPUT.txt"

#getAllUsers function

function get_all_user(){
    echo -e '\f' >> "$fpipe"
    alluser=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '$7=="/bin/bash" {print $1"\\n"$3"\\n"$4"\\n"}' | tr -d '[:space:]' )
    echo -e $alluser > "$fpipe"
}

export -f get_all_user

#get_selected_user function
function get_selected_user()
{
    echo -e '\f' > "$temp"
    echo "$1" > "$temp"
    cat $temp
}

export -f get_selected_user

#adduser function
function run_adduser()
{
      # check for this in '/etc/passwd' and '/etc/shadow'
      # $2 is the username
      # $3 is the password
      if id "$2" &>/dev/null; then
        zenity --warning \
        --text="Username existed. Please enter another username."
      else
        useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 $3) -s /bin/bash -G sudo $2 
        zenity --info \
        --text="User added successfully."
      fi
}

export -f run_adduser

# Users information tab
get_all_user
yad --plug=$KEY --tabnum=1 --width=600 --height=450 --expand-column=0 --limit=10 \
--list --select-action='@bash -c "get_selected_user %s %s %s"' --column="Username" --column="UID" --column="GID" <&3 & 

exec 3>&-
```

Comment: You use `fpipe` parameter before you define it.

Comment: quote this properly: `trap 'rm -f "$fpipe" "$fts"'`

Comment: You need to open a file descriptor on the fifo. `exec {fd}<> "$fpipe"`. Then `exec "$fd">&-` to close it (`{fd}` chooses an fd automatically, instead of hardcoding 3). You can also write to the file descriptor: `echo -e "$alluser" >&"$fd"`.